# How can I remove embedded quotes in JSON formatted submission to Flask

Tags: python, json, flask, nltk

I am writing a small part-of-speech application in Flask and the Python Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK) to return the parts-of-speech for a sentence submitted to the Flask API.  This works fine if the JSON submitted data is formatted properly.  But how can I validate the JSON data and transform it as needed if the data submitted contains embedded quotes inside the submission.

**Valid submission**

```
{
   "pos_submission":"This is a valid json format."
}
```

**Invalid submission** (but very likely to occur)

```
{
   "pos_submission":"This is an "invalid" json format due to the embedded quotes."
}
```

Code:

```
    from flask import Flask, jsonify
    from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('pos', methods=['POST']) 
    def pos():
        data = request.json 
        data_submission = data["pos_submission"] # pull the sentence into variable
        tokenized_submission = word_tokenize(data_submission) # tokenize sentence
        pos_results = pos_tag(tokenized submission) # get part of speech results
        pos_results=dict([('Data_Submission', data_submission),
      ('POS_Tags',pos_results)]) # create a pos dictionary object 
        return jsonify(pos_results) # return dictionary object as json


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='127.0.0.1', threaded=True, port=5000, debug=True)
```

What are my best options here to correct the embedded quotes in the submission and return the parts-of-speech?

Comment: By far the best approach is to fix the program that generates the invalid JSON. Is this an option?

Comment: I agree it would ideal to correct the embedded quotes before the API call but unfortunately, this is not really an option.  I was hoping for a clever way to deal with the quotes once the API call came in.

Comment: Why not update the client side code.

Comment: Yes, that is an excellent suggestion.  It is definitely a corner case that the json will be improperly formatted.  Many of the folks using this APi do have they code properly format the json request.  However, a few of the teams using the API, have submitted with improperly formatted json entries.  I am just trying to figure out a way to handle that on the Flask server while still returning the requested response, in this case the parts-of-speech.